# Do we need a custom Verilog syntax highlighter?

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

Verilog is a C-like language.  It uses a similar layout, has equivalent control keywords, and highlights OK when using the C syntax highlighter:

Of course, it has some notable differences, including many more keywords, especially the `begin` and `end` keywords as opposed to curly braces, and various syntactic incompatibilities like `@` and `'`.

At the moment, I've set up the syntax highlighter to use `lang-c` to highlight Verilog.  In my opinion, it's often better than nothing:

[image: decent highlighting]

but it's not great. For example, `'` is used in places it's not used in C, causing stuff like:

[image: bad highlighting]

Verilog uses `'` in code, but the highlighter assumes that it's a character delimiter.

Would you rather have `lang-c` or nothing?  How important would a custom highlighter be?  There are currently only 29 questions with the [verilog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verilog) tag, is this important enough to make all the visitors download a couple hundred bytes of Javascript?

Please report any major highlighting mistakes,  <strike>and use `<!-- language: lang-none -->` to prefix any code blocks that you don't want syntax highlighted.</strike> Broken, see [lang-none specifier only works in preview](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/835/lang-none-specifier-only-works-in-preview).

Comment: you can submit a custom syntax highlighter to the google prettify project -- http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/