# lang-none specifier only works in preview

Tags: bug, status-norepro, syntax-highlighting

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16910/what-transaction-modeling-and-packet-linking-frameworks-exist) uses an ASCII diagram and has the verilog tag.

To avoid syntax highlighting, I used the `<!-- language: lang-none -->` directive.  Per the [SO FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting),

> To specify that you don't want any syntax highlighting for a code block, use
>   `<!-- language: lang-none -->`

this should cause the highlighting to dissapear.

It did, in the preview:

> [image: preview]

<sub><sup>Note: this is a dummy edit a little more than 5 minutes after the initial edit, which also displayed the bug</sup></sub>

But it didn't take when I saved the edits:

> [image: actual]

Why is this?

Comment: Looks like it also failed to take on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/13718/857

Comment: And http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/19582/857 - better stop for a while....

Comment: It seems to me that automatic syntax highlighting is a bad idea.  It might marginally help in some rare cases, but probably will cause more trouble than it will help.  People shouldn't be posting long code here anyway, and syntax highlighting doesn't add much to short code snippets.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, we support firmware troubleshooting, why not allow people to post long snippets of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have absolutely no idea what was broken here. It works now, so *something* has changed, but I don't know what. I even compiled  and ran the code as it was back when you encountered this issue; still no luck.

I'll tag this [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), not because I'm saying you were imagining this (you obviously weren't), but because I really can't reproduce it. If you see this again, please let me know.